# MX Linux - Network missing

Tags: networking, systemd, mx-linux

I did sudo apt get update / upgrade, and installed the rpi-installer. And after that I lost all network connectivity.

After that, it seemed like my network has been disabled. No access to the internet or local file shares. The networking service is not running. At the boot screen, when I see advanced options, if I select the "...(systemd)" option I have network again.

Any ideas how to fix so I do not need to go into the advanced options?

Comment: Probably NetworkManager not running. Run it manually or enable NetworkManager service for SysV init.

Comment: @AbdullahIbnFulan Tried to run manually by services network start and service NetworkManager start and it  said unrecognized service. /etc/int.d/network start  came back with no file or directory.

Comment: You have to symlink the service file to /etc/init.d

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-sysvinit-compat
```

Then reboot normally. That works for me.